# How do I separate a string: Pig Latin Translator

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginning programmer and I have to write a Pig Latin Translator. I have this code that will translate and single word. I just need to know how I could separate the input into separate strings via spaces. Once I can understand this (and I believe I am trying to understand arrays, not sure?) I will be able to edit the code as necessary. Thanks a lot!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine();  
    String a = str.substring(0,1);
    String b = str.substring(0,2);
    String c = str.substring(0,3);
    String d = str.substring(0,4);
    String answer = "";
    if (str.startsWith("a") || str.startsWith("e") || str.startsWith("i") ||  str.startsWith("o") || str.startsWith("u"))
    {
      System.out.print(str + "way");
      }
    else
      {
        answer = str.substring(2,str.length());
        String answer2 = str.substring(1,str.length());
        String answer3 = str.substring(3,str.length());
        String answer4 = str.substring(4,str.length());
        if (!(d.contains("a") || d.contains("e") || d.contains("i") || d.contains("o") || d.contains("u")))
          {
            System.out.print(answer4 + d + "ay");
            }
        else if (!(c.contains("a") || c.contains("e") || c.contains("i") || c.contains("o") || c.contains("u")))
          {
            System.out.print(answer3 + c + "ay");
            }
        else if (!(b.contains("a") || b.contains("e") || b.contains("i") || b.contains("o") || b.contains("u")))
          {
            System.out.print(answer + b + "ay");
            }
        else if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
      {
        System.out.print(answer2 + a + "ay");
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
```

`.split("\\s+")` splits `str` on each occurrence of one or more whitespace characters.

I suggest you refactor the code for processing a single word out to its own method, and apply it to every element of `words`.

Comment: I feel like this should work, but what is supposed to happen when I create String words? Also I printed words and it gave me this: [Ljava.lang.String;@1f86e79

Comment: @Gihadi `import java.util.Arrays` and print `Arrays.toString(words)` (arrays don't override the `toString()` method, annoyingly, so we have to resort to using this utility method).

Answer (score 0):

Separating strings via spaces is quite simple.  You already know how to wrap a Scanner around System.In -- if you wrap a Scanner around a String, its default token delimiter is a space.

```
String test = "Hello world, my name is bob.";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(test);
while (sc.hasNext())
    System.out.println(sc.next());
```

The output of this code block will be

```
Hello
world,
my
name
is
bob.
```

You can incorporate this logic to break apart your input and pig-latinize each word individually.

Comment: Also learn arshajii's answer.  It's a simpler way to do it without using the overhead of a new Scanner.  Two ways to skin the cat, his is a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

May want to try [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/), although it's real use is probably more for complex parsing situations. For what you want, doing String.split method is probably easier.

Comment: arshajii gives an example of using String.split